# Fetch - не удается выполнить простейший запрос

Tags: javascript, http, reactjs, cors

localhost:3000 - клиент на React

localhost:8080 - сервер на NodeJS

Я написал вот такой класс для вызова методов API сервера:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Server {
  static call(apiMethod, params = {}, httpMethod = 'POST') {
    return fetch('http://localhost:8080/' + apiMethod, {
      mode: 'no-cors',
      method: httpMethod,
      body: params
    });
  }
}

export default Server;
```

Пытаюсь его использовать:

```
process() {
  let method = this.state.mode;
  Server.call(method, {
    name: this.state.user,
    password: this.state.password
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

В консоли получаю:[image: Пример ответа]

Не понимаю, в чем проблема? Как получить ответ от сервера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, удалось разобраться. Спасибо @Sapphiron за помощь.

Вся проблема оказалась в CORS и заголовках сервера. Для того, чтобы все заработало я поправил код на сервере (NodeJS + Express) вот так:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
    next();
});
```

И код на клиенте:

```
class Server {
  static call(apiMethod, params = {}, httpMethod = 'POST') {
    return fetch('http://localhost:8080/' + apiMethod, {
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
      mode: 'cors',
      method: httpMethod,
      body: JSON.stringify(params)
    }).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    });
  }
}
```

Теперь все работает =)

Answer (score 2):

`Then` возвращает `Promise`. Когда получен ответ, он отправляется в первый `then` с объектом `response`. Уже из `response` можно забрать тело ответа, используя один из методов.

```
response.arrayBuffer()
response.blob()
response.formData()
response.json()
response.text()
```

Эти методы так же возвращают `Promise`, который необходимо обработать в `then` или `catch`. Т.е. функция должна выглядеть примерно так

```
  Server.call(method, {
    name: this.state.user,
    password: this.state.password
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне кажется, проблема не в этом. Мне попросту то ли не приходит вовсе, то ли приходит пустой ответ. Не могу понять, почему это происходит. Я попробовал `response.blob()`, вывел 
в консоль `[[PromiseValue]] size:0 type :""`

Comment: Что вы ждете в ответ? Файл?

Comment: Нет, должен прийти обычный JSON, но его нет :(

Comment: Тогда сделайте так, как в моем примере. `return response.json();` вернет в `then` json.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, вот этот код: https://pastebin.com/J8wkfYkm Он выдает три сообщения - null, 0, Unexpected input, хотя я, вроде, сделал все как вы и сказали.

Comment: `mode: 'no-cors',` не позволяет читать данные из ответа. Если это `cors` запрос, измените на `mode: 'cors'` и добавьте `cors` заголовки на сервере.